# Any way to prevent Node.js update automatically on Windows 10?

Tags: node.js, windows

I installed Node.js on Windows version v14.15.5 for a project without checking anything on the prompts during the installation. Then at some point Node.js automagically updates to latest version v16.*.*. Any way to disable this update regardless what is happening in the code of the project or elsewhere in the system. Just wish to always keep same version that was installed or specific version, in this case v14.15.5. Thank you

Comment: If you wish a certain version of Node.js for a certain project then you need to use some Node.js version manager like `nvm`

Comment: Just to clarify, NVM as node version manager and not NPM, correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly, nvm

Comment: My installation of nodejs on Windows 11 NEVER updates itself.  I just installed nodejs from the Windows installer and picked the version I wanted at the time of install.   It has never in 5 years updated itself.

Answer (score 0):

Except `nvm` there is another reason for the automatic update.

**Disclaimer**: In my case it was Chocolatey.

Chocolatey can be installed as last step of node installation.

You should be able to stop this with chocolatey [`pin`](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/commands/pin) command.
Something like this:

```
choco pin add -n="nodejs"
choco pin add -n="nodejs.install"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am not using Chocolatey at the moment but worth a try. If anyone else can confirm this it would be great and then we can mark this as one of the accepted answers.